# Training a NLP Model to Translate User Descriptions to Predefined Part Numbers

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am working on mapping user input descriptions to specific part number categories. I have a large dataset of part numbers and their associated descriptions. Here's an example of what the data looks like:

```js
"52119A": "COVER, FRONT BUMPER",
"81110": "HEADLAMP ASSY, RH",
"52134I": "REINFORCEMENT, FRONT BUMPER BAR, LH"
"53301F": "PANEL SUB-ASSY, FRONT",
"87050": "RADIATOR ASSY, AIR CONDITIONER"
```

The challenge is to develop a system that can accurately map a user's description of the part to the appropriate part number. For instance, if a user inputs "FRONT BUMPER COVER", the system should be able to translate this to "52119A": "COVER, FRONT BUMPER".

I'm considering using Natural Language Processing (NLP) or some sort of AI for this problem, but I'm unsure of the best approach. Specifically, I would appreciate guidance on:

1. What type of NLP or AI model would be most appropriate for this task?
2. How should I go about training the model? What kind of training data will I need and how much of it?
3. What libraries or tools would be useful? I have a little bit of familiarity with Python-based libraries (Ive used NLTK, and SpaCy - I'm open to using others if they're better).
4. Are there any similar projects or resources that I could reference to get a better understanding of how to tackle this problem?

Comment: How big is your dataset? do you have tagged examples? How many labels(part numbers) are there?

Comment: As advised in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76640891/building-a-knowledge-graph-and-utilizing-machine-learning-for-semantic-matching#comment135123807_76640891

Comment: @SaharMillis I don't have a tagged dataset at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a simple `TF-IDF` (or `count vectorizer` / BOW).
Based on your example, it should give you nice results.
This would be your baseline.

If your queries from the users look more like natural text, you can consider using a more complex approach; and using a `BERT`-like model, for a multi-class classification task.

To answer your question, these models need thousands of data samples.
You should have this data from the system/app/platform you're building this for. If you don't have any data, you can create a synthetic dataset, or work within a Few-shot concept.

Python-based libraries:
`NLTK`, `Spacy`, `Transformers`(HuggingFace), `SK-learn`, etc - all are great.

Similar projects:

[multi-class text classification with bert](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-deep-learning-using-bert-b59ca2f5c613)
[Multi-Class Text Classification with BERT, RoBERTa, XLNet, XLM, and DistilBERT](https://medium.com/swlh/simple-transformers-multi-class-text-classification-with-bert-roberta-xlnet-xlm-and-8b585000ce3a)

Also, you can use StarCode to get help with all this code.